# Open Sans rendered as Helvetica

Tags: html, css

I have the simpliest html code along these lines:

```
<p class="class1">Text here</p>
```

And css like:

```
.class1 {
    font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

And Open-Sans connected in the head using Google generated link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800&amp;subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
```

However my browsers render the text using Helvetica font. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: `font-family: 'Open Sans'` (remove the dash)

Comment: + in the link represents space. So your CSS should be like `font-family: 'Open Sans'`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I missed that. Works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using font family name incorrectly

[Google web font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open%20Sans)

[image]